# How can I retrieve image from mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

in mongodb my image is saved as
 `image: BinData(0, 'QzpcZmFrZXBhdGhcV2hhdHNBcHAgSW1hZ2UgMjAyMi0xMi0wNCB40Ny4zMS5qcGc=')`

I am trying to access this image in my frontend Reactjs  like this

`{userData.image ? <img src={`data:image;base64,${userData.image}`} alt="User profile image" width="200" height="200" /> : <img src={'./Images/profile.png'} alt="Default image" width="200" height="200" /> }`

but it is not showing this image

How can i access this decode this image back to its original form

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can display the images in your React component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function User() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUsers() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/users');
        setUserData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map(user => (
        <div key={userData._id}>
          {/* Display the user's image */}
          <img
            src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${Buffer.from(userData.image).toString('base64')}`}
            alt="User Image"
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={userData.image ? 'data:image;base64,' + userData.image : './Images/profile.png'} alt={userData.image ? 'User profile image' : 'Default image'} width="200" height="200" />
```

It's actually better to do it this way.

Comment: still it is not getting picture from database

Comment: This string (QzpcZmFrZXBhdGhcV2hhdHNBcHAgSW1hZ2UgMjAyMi0xMi0wNCB40Ny4zMS5qcGc=) is not valid as base64.
If you already have a base64 string, save it with Code or string type.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example with typescript:

```js
    public async getThumbnail(id: string): Promise<string> {
        const result = await this.collection.findOne<any>({ _id: id }, {
            projection: { _id: 0, thumbnailImage: 1 }
        })

        return result.thumbnailImage.buffer.toString("base64");
    }
```

`thumbnailImage` is the Buffer field in the database. This will return the binary in the DB as base64 string.

On the other hand if you return the buffer, then you can return the image as image.

For example with Koa, inside a get method:

```js
router.get("/thumbnail/:id", async ctx => {
   ctx.body = await getThumbnail(ctx.params.id);
   ctx.type = "image/png";
})
```

Then just use the `<img src="/thumbnail/my_id">`